# sequencing UIImageView frame(s) animation & CGTransform animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nstimer

I'd like help on some strategies to sequence some animations.

I subclassed UIImageView so that I could write some custom animation actions on an image.  I implemented a few methods to be used as actions that I could call on my image
example:

```
-(void)rotateAnim; //rotates the image by a few degrees using a CGAffine Transform

-(void)numbersFlashAnim; //uses the UIImageVew.animationImages array for a 14 frame animation.

-(void)moveLeftAnim; //uses another CGAffine Transform to change the imageView's position.
```

In my viewDidLoad method I create an instance of my UIImageView subclass. What ways exist to call these animations in sequence?

I was thinking about using an NSTimer to handle the animations, but wasn't sure if you could  write an NSTimer object to handle multiple method calls.

example:

```
[imageView rotateAnim]; //when this animation is done, I want to call:
[imageView numbersFlashAnim];
```

I've seen several questions regarding the use of an NSTimer, but none that specifically relate to this problem.  Note: I saw that the dev docs on apple's site also recommend the use of the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: in some cases but was wondering if that would offer enough flexibility.

Additionally, I've already taken a look at the Cocos2d framework, and although I can use their methods ~(Sequence actions: etc, ) I'm choosing to solve this problem with UIKit/Foundation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use animation? I mean you can rotate your image inside 
[UIView beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context] block. There you can add a delegate method that will be called after current animation ends. And there you can call your numbersFlashAnim.
(Sorry for my english ;-) )

Comment: Yes, I used an animation block and wrapped in a method so i could call the entire animation with one line of code.  I haven't added any delegates. so i'll check for that.  Could I use the animation delegate for the animationFrames as well?

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, but I cannot understand what do you mean under animationFrames. You can call rotation of your imageView inside te animation block. Then you can set a method with the second part pf your animation, that will be fired after your animation will be finished.